# WordPress 404 header for custom 404 page

Tags: wordpress, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I built a simple plugin that I can use to quickly create a "pretty" custom 404 page that resides in the WordPress pages area where it can be easily edited. I recently discovered that my plugin is not sending the proper 404 not found header when Google webmaster tools informed me that I've had an increase in soft 404s. As you can see in the code below, I first send the 404 Not found header and then call a 301 permanent redirect.

Conceptually I would think this should work (and I've seen this used in other 404 plugins), but it doesn't. The only way I could get the 404 header to show up is if I sent the header after the location header, but that kind of defeats the purpose as it shows a blank page. I'm not really sure how to best make this work in a WordPress plugin, and I want to make sure I can some how make this work within WordPress's page structure.

Here's the function:

```
if ($wp_query->is_404) {
    $page_title = $this->options['404_page_title'];
    $redirect_404_url = esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_title($page_title)));
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:" . $redirect_404_url);
    die;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can use two `header()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it! Thanks Brady for helping point me in the right direction!

First I set up a function to redirect to the page created by the plugin on a 404 error. Then, I created another function that adds a 404 header status to the page if the page title matches the page title of the 404 page created by the plugin. Finally, I hooked the functions into my constructor. Piece of cake. :)

404 Redirect Function:

```
public function redirect_404() {
    global $options, $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->is_404) {
        $page_title = $this->options['404_page_title'];
        $redirect_404_url = esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_title($page_title)));
        wp_redirect($redirect_404_url);
        add_action('wp', array(&$this, 'redirection'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Apply 404 Header to Page Function:

```
public function is_page_function() {
    global $options;
    $page_title = $this->options['404_page_title'];
    if (is_page($page_title)) {
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    }
}
```

Actions:

```
add_action('template_redirect', array( &$this, 'redirect_404' ), 0);
add_action('template_redirect', array( &$this, 'is_page_function'), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to your 404 page, send the 404 header and simply print out the 404 page content.

This is untested, but the idea is something like this...

```
<?php
if ($wp_query->is_404) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    $page_title = $this->options['404_page_title'];
    // Override the current post to the 404 page
    $GLOBALS['post'] = get_page_by_title($page_title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brady! I haven't had a chance to test yet but I'll let you know soon.

Comment: That code didn't work, but the concept seems good. I'll dive into this more when I have some time later this week.

Comment: Take a look at this [wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) on custom 404 pages.  Your template will need a call to the_content(); for it to display what you have created in the CMS editor.

Comment: If it doesn't work to set the post using the global. You could also register a short code (see [shortcode api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)) with a custom method that pulls your page using get_page_by_title then echos $page->post_content;.  You can call the shortcode in your 404.php template using echo do_shortcode( '[my-shortcode]' );

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to completely avoid 404.php as this needs to match the style and look of the user's site. If I create and call a custom 404.php page, there's no way I can possibly ensure that it works with every site.

Comment: The admin CMS/page editor only manages the content of the pages, not the layout or overall template.  You'll need the 404.php part to manage the template (similar to any other static page template), while the page editor can be used to manage the content of that page. I think this is the best solution to utilize wordpress' built in tools.  Otherwise, you could try just echoing $page->post_content; and exit(), but you're shortcutting the templating engine.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use my own custom made 404.php because there's no way I can ensure that it will match the style and theme of every site (at least, to my knowledge). The method I'm using now bypasses it all together and just creates another page which uses their default page template. Watch what happens when I use this method on the 2012 theme: testing.wpovernight.com/adfdsf.

Comment: By the way, thanks for being engaged with this. I'm giving you an upvote :)

Comment: Check out this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/notfoundorg-404-page/.  They override the 404 page with their own content, but they don't honor the site template (tested, it does work with latest WP version). Source code: https://github.com/katzgrau/wp-notfound-org

Comment: I ended up getting an answer that solves my problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!